# Why can't I force unwrap my $string to use as a TextField value?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

This gives me the following error:
Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Binding<Person?>

I don't understand why I can't force unwrap a binding?

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var person: Person? = Person(name: "Peter")
    
    var body: some View {
        if person != nil {
            TextField("", text: $person!.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Off topic but are you sure you want to have a model object like Person as a State variable?

Comment: Why is `person` optional at all ?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson You are correct, I won't. I extracted this from my code to make the example simple.

Comment: @vadian. The code is extracted to make the example simple. But say you have a List of persons to select from, one option is to not have a person selected at all. In that case, Person would be nil, so I need to count for that

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a list then the object is an array and *none selected* is an empty array. And if the view is a row view in a List it's not going to be displayed if the row is not selected. What I try to say is that unlike the Swift language SwiftUI relies heavily on non-optionals and you should first look for a design which avoid optionals.

Comment: @vadian. Good point, and as a newbie there's a lot to learn. As far as I understand, the selection of a list needs to be a binded optional, selectedListItem?. So this can be nil. I'm using SwiftUI for a MacOS app, so simple stuff like removing or renaming items on a list seems to get more complicated. In MacOS, you don't have the editMode that allows you to _swipe to delete_ etc. (as far as I understand?), so I needed to go alternative ways.

Answer (score 6):

When you declare a `State` variable in your view, you'll get a `Binding` to the value by adding a leading `$` to the variable's name.
So, in your code, you'll have a `$person` that is binding to an optional `Person` type. `$person` is `Binding<Person?>`

To pass value to `TextField` you'll need a `Binding<String>`. you can't force-unwrap `$person` because it's not an optional value. It's a `Binding` to an optional type. To access the `name` field inside the `Person` struct, you'll need a `Binding<Person>` instead.
Fortunately, there's a method to get what you want.
By using [this initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/init(_:)-5z9t9), you'll have a `Binding<Person>?`. Note that now instead of a `Binding` to an optional, you have an optional `Binding`.
You should be able to use this new binding like this:

```
// Binding($person) returns Binding<Person>? 
TextField("", text: Binding($person)!.name)
```

Update:
As @Jessy mentioned in the comments, instead of force-unwrapping the optional binding, we can use `map` to transform the returned `Binding` to a `TextField`

```
var body: some View {
   Binding($person).map {
     TextField("", text: $0.name)
   }
}
```

Comment: That initializer is a good part of the solution, but that `!` is not a good way to go. `if let` or what I did with `map` are better; Update your answer and I'll delete mine, because you have more complete information.

Comment: Now, how cool was that. Not totally sure I understand what happened there with the mapping, but thanks, guys, this just totally sorted it for me!